# Picking a random phrase in an array

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain why this is not working for me?  I have an array and I want to pick a random string from it.  Unfortunately, when I execute it does pick a phrase randomly, however it always picks the same string if I run it again?

```js
let random = ['OMG...try again!', 'Try harder!', 'You can do better than you!', 'This is easy!', 'Too high!', 'Keep guessing']
let randomPick = random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];
console.log(randomPick);
```

Here is what happens when I use the console to test.

[image]

Comment: When I run the script it logs different values as expected. what is the exact problem ?

Comment: I pasted your code into a snippet and it appears to work

Comment: Your snippet works as expected returning different values.

Comment: When I put it into the console it always prints the same string?

Comment: Well, that was random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let random = ['OMG...try again!', 'Try harder!', 'You can do better than you!', 'This is easy!', 'Too high!', 'Keep guessing']
let randomPick = random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];
console.log(randomPick);
console.log(randomPick);
console.log(randomPick);
console.log(randomPick);
```

Your code *functionality* works just fine- but when you run just the final line again, you're simply printing a variable rather than running the random selection again.

`console.log(randomPick);` prints out the contents of the variable `randomPick`, which had a random element in your array assigned to it, once.

---

In order to get `console.log(randomPick);` to print a new phrase each time, you'll need to convert `randomPick` into a *function* rather than a variable:

```js
function randomPick() {
  let random = ['OMG...try again!', 'Try harder!', 'You can do better than you!', 'This is easy!', 'Too high!', 'Keep guessing'];
  return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];
}
console.log(randomPick());
console.log(randomPick());
console.log(randomPick());
console.log(randomPick());
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh!  I totally got ahead of myself and didn't think the whole process through.  Total brain melt!  Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

try using  this. If it doesn't work, then just comment or something and I'll look at it and find an answer

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("onload", name, false);

function name() {
 
random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)]

}
</script>
```

Comment: But this doesn't change anything. The code above is working correctly.

Comment: lol I didnt see that